# No display when querying using PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to build a table using in PHP with some text coming from mysql database:

However, when I echo the table, the page comes up as blank

Here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <title>Pre Order</title>

</head>
<body>
<div class="page">

<?php 
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 
$conn2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 


$form=$_POST;
$a=$form['a'];
$b=$form['b'];
$c=$form['c'];
$accountnumber=$form['accountnumber']

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE A='$a' AND B='$b' AND C='$c'");
$stmt2 = $conn2->query("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerCode='$accountnumber'");

$data = '';

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {


$data .= "<table>";
$data .= "<tr><td>Account Number: </td>";


echo $data;
}
}

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I remove the mysql connection, the echo works fine.

The file is a .php file.

Comment: What does `connect.php` do? Maybe the database is restricting three simultaneous connections to it. Why not just use one connection?

Comment: connect.php is just the mysql username and password information.

Comment: `$row2 = $stmt2->fet(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` should be `->fetch`, is this your real code?

Comment: no this is not my real code. changed it and still a blank page

Comment: You should include your real code. Besides the obvious SQL injection, there's nothing really wrong with your code, besides the multiple connections too.

Comment: sry because i am doing this for a firm and non-disclosure, i cannot reveal the entire code. however, this is a basic gist of the code.

Comment: Add **<?php ini_set('display_errors',1); ?>** at the top of your code.

Comment: From the copy-paste or is this in the original? `while ($row2 = $stmt2->fet(` should be `fetch` not `fet`

Comment: Also, did you know you can use the same connection to make multiple queries?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more code, there's nothing more I can suggest, however:

```
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$contracts = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE A = :a AND B = :b AND C = :c');
$contracts->bindParam(':a', $_POST['a']);
$contracts->bindParam(':b', $_POST['b']);
$contracts->bindParam(':c', $_POST['c']);
$contracts->execute();

$customers = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerCode = :code');
$customers->bindParam(':code', $_POST['accountnumber']);
$customers->execute();

while ($customer = $customers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    print_r($customer);

while ($contract = $contracts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
   print_r($contract);
```

One connection, and make sure you're preparing and executing your queries. I think because you didn't do this, a single quote or an invalid character broke your query.

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in` getting this error for `$contracts->bindParam(':a', $_POST['a']);`

Comment: Make sure your table Contracts has the columns A, B, and C, and that your Customers table has the column CustomerCode. Make sure `$conn` is connected properly, and also `print_r($conn->->errorInfo());` right after the prepare.